# What’s the meaning of ‘tickled them in exactly the right place’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence, what’s the meaning of ‘tickled them in exactly the right place’?

> There were a hundred and forty-two staircases at Hogwarts: wide, sweeping ones; narrow, rickety ones; some that led somewhere different on a Friday; some with a vanishing step halfway up that you had to remember to jump. Then there were doors that wouldn't open unless you asked politely, or **tickled them in exactly the right place**, and doors that weren't really doors at all, but solid walls just pretending.

Comment: It means the walls would open if they were tickled in exactly the right place. No more, no less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it means exactly what it says, just gently brush one specific spot on the door to make it open.

It's probably a play on an idiom of *tickling/scratching/brushing just the right way/spot* which means saying or doing something for someone that makes them unusually favorable towards you, say, praising something that seems they are secretly very proud of, or giving a [gift](http://www.mediabistro.com/galleycat/tom-hanks-accepts-depression-era-typewriter-bribe_b58881) that another person would consider trite, that holds a very special appeal to the one you're giving it to.

This is opposite to *brushing the wrong way*, saying or doing a thing that others would consider at worst slightly iring, more commonly totally neutral, while the person finds it unusually upsetting.

Answer (score 1):

Each door has a very narrow, specific area that you have to tickle so that it opens. So unless you ask the door politely or tickle in that exact spot, it won't open.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this is how tickling works sometimes. A lot of people have certain "tickle spots" – you can try to tickle someone and get no reaction, but then move your hand just a little bit, and then suddenly, they are being tickled. In order to tickle them, you must do so in _exactly the right place_.